# Understanding complex solutions to real differential equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ and consider the differential equation $x'(t)=Ax(t)$. I want to solve it using a complex solution

$$x(t)=ve^{\lambda t} \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{C} , v\in \mathbb{C}^2 $$

Now I know $x(t)$ is only a solution if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue to the corresponding eigenvector $v$. Furthermore, let the two eigenvalues be complex conjugated i.e. $\lambda_1,\lambda_2= a \pm bi\in \mathbb{C}$.

**Now onto the question**: With Euler it follows that:

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:einstein}
    x(t)= c_1 ve^{at}(\cos(bt)+i\sin(bt))+ c_2 we^{at}(\cos(bt)-i\sin(bt))\tag{*}
  \end{equation}

is a solution to the D.EQ, where $v,w$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. Now because the differential equation is real, **the solution must be real and it is given by** : $$x(t)=r_1 e^{at}(\Re(v)\cos(bt)+\Im(v)\sin(bt))+ r_2 e^{at}(\Re(w)\cos(bt)-\Im(w)\sin(bt))$$

with $r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and those are supposed to be the real and imaginary functions Re(v) and Im(v).

**How does one obtain the real solution from the complex solution (*)?**

Comment: Shouldn't $x(t)$ contain two different real functions? (since $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: The exponential function is the eigenfunction to the differential operator. The complex exponential function splits into additive real even cosine part and imaginary odd sine parts.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a real $2\times2$ matrix, and if

$$t\mapsto{\bf z}(t)=\bigl(z_1(t),z_2(t)\bigr)\in{\mathbb C}^2$$
is a complex valued solution of the ODE system
$${\bf z}'=A\,{\bf z}\ ,\tag{1}$$
then automatically 
$$t\mapsto {\bf x}(t):={\rm Re}({\bf z}(t))\in{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad t\mapsto {\bf y}(t):={\rm Im}({\bf z}(t))\in{\mathbb R}^2$$
are real valued solutions of $(1)$. This is easily verified by plugging in.